# Number to Text Variable not showing in HTML

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a variable named "Timer" and I am trying to make the number go up by one, then display the number. The issue is, The "Test Successful!" part isn't even showing. I am not getting any errors in Visual Studio Code.

```
function Test() {
    var Timer = 4
    setInterval(Rickroll, 1000)
}

function Rickroll() {
    if (Timer > 0 ) {
    Timer -= 1
    }
    var TimerString = Timer.toString();
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = "Test Successful! Sending you to another website in: "+TimerString;
}
```

Comment: You should really learn a bit more JavaScript before asking a question like this on StackOverflow. This question is related to the very basics of JavaScript, and it is usually expected that you understand to some extent what you are doing on this Q&A forum (not to mention you should understand the language or topic at least fairly well). This particular problem is seemingly related to scope, which you can read about [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-scope-in-javascript-cbd957022652/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

Answer (score 1):

variable Timer is not global.
If you want to use Timer in Test() and Rickroll function, you have to define Timer variable as a global variable.
This code will be working well.

```
var Timer = 0
function Test() {

    if (Timer < 3) {
       setInterval(Rickroll, 1000)
    }
}

function Rickroll() {
    Timer += 1
    var TimerString = Timer.toString();
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = "Test Successful! Sending you to another 
                                                website in: "+TimerString;
}
```

Comment: This also does not work, because `var` when defined in a function is restrained to that current function; it is not automatically put into the global scope. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code.
Before, I wrote your function without fix.